# How to design an algorithm to put elements into groups with constraints?

Tags: algorithm, constraints, combinations

I was given a task of putting students into groups (to prepare a coding camp), but with several constraints. Though I've finished the task by hand, I'd like to know is there already exist some algorithms for tasks like this, or how can I design such an algorithm.

---

**Background**: 40 students in total, with these attributes:

- gender: F/M
- grade: Year 1/2
- school: School 1/School 2/...
- early assessment result: Rank from 1 to 40

**Constraints**: All of them needs to be satisfied.

1. Exactly 4 people per group
2. Each group needs to have at least a girl
3. Each group needs to have at least a Year 2 student
4. 4 group members needs to come from 4 different schools
5. Each group needs to have at least a student who ranked top 10 in early assessment

**What I'm expecting**:

- The Best: An existing algorithm/program for these kind of problems
- Or, An algorithm for this specific problem
- Or at least, Some ideas of creating an algorithm for this specific problem

---

**My thoughts**:
Since I've successed in making groups by hand, I know that such a solution indeed exists for my current dataset. But if I need an algorithm to find a solution for me, it should first try to check whether a solution even exists, by check if the number of girl / Year 2 students is greater than 10 (with pigeonhole principle), and some other conditions. And obviously, Constraint 5 is the easiest, and can provide a base solution for the rest. However, I still can not find a systematic way of doing it. Perhaps bruteforce and randomization can help? I'm not sure.

And sorry, since the data is confidential, I can not post it.

---

**Update**: After consulting a friend, here is a possible method:

1. First put the top 1 to 10 into 10 different groups.
2. Then iterate through groups. If the only person in the group is a boy/girl, try to add a girl/boy from a different school.
3. Then the problem size is reduced from 2^40 to 2^20, making bruthforce a viable solution.

Comment: Is it a homework?

Comment: @Damien Not a homework, but I'm just trying to find better ways to tackle this task.

Comment: To be clear, should there be exactly 4 members per group, or at least 4 members per group?

Comment: @SecularisticSloth Sorry for the vague description. Exactly 4 member per group.